# c# Open XML split runs into individual words

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using Open XML to process text in a Word document.  I am trying to split certain runs into individual words (separate by white space)  for further processing ONLY if the text matches a key words.

```
 foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>()){
     string t1 = text.Text; 
     if (t1.Contains("keyWord"))
     {
      // I need to split the run here so that I have 1 run per word so that I can
      // Process the runs individually (and add bookmarks if additional conditions are met   

     }
  }
```

Is there an easy way to split the runs in this way?  I couldn't find anything simple.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, although I don't really understand the purpose of why you would split the words into individual Runs.

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\test\test.docx", true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    var runs = mainPart.Document.Descendants<Run>().ToList();

    foreach (Run run in runs)
    {
        var text = run.GetFirstChild<Text>();
        if(text.Text.Contains("KEYWORD"))
        {
            string[] words = text.Text.Split(' ');
            for(int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
            {
                string word = words[i];
                var newRun = (Run)run.Clone();
                string newWord = word + (i < words.Count() ? " " : "");
                Text newRunText = newRun.GetFirstChild<Text>();
                newRunText.Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve;
                newRunText.Text = newWord;
                run.Parent.InsertBefore(newRun, run);
            }
            run.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It works by checking the Text element of the Run for your keyword, splitting the sentence into individual words, and the cloning the Run, and replace the text with the single word. Then insert the new Run before the old Run, and when done, remove the old Run.
I had to add the SpaceProcessingModeValue for it to preserve the space in the test i did with a simple .docx document containing the sentence "This is a search for the word KEYWORD"

Hope it helps.